# Python check if list is present in list of lists for detecting cycles

Tags: python, list

I have a sample of about 60000 data points and in an iterative algorithm, in each step, depending on some criterion, I either 'remove' (set to NaN) one of those data points or 'add' one of the previously removed data points back into the sample (set back to its original value). In order to avoid that the algorithm falls into an infinite loop, the sample should always be different in each iteration. I therefore keep track of the data points that are currently removed in each iteration and store the element indices in a list as follows:

- Iteration 1: *data_state_list* = [[2]] (element with array index 2 is removed)
- Iteration 2: *data_state_list* = [[2],[2,3]] (element with array index 3 is removed)
- Iteration 3: *data_state_list* = [[2],[2,3],[2,3,1]]
- Iteration 4: *data_state_list* = [[2],[2,3],[2,3,1],[2,1]] (element with array index 3 is re-added)
- Iteration 5: *data_state_list* = [[2],[2,3],[2,3,1],[2,1],[2,1,4]]
- Iteration 6: *data_state_list* = [[2],[2,3],[2,3,1],[2,1],[2,1,4],[2,1,4,3]]

Now in the current iteration 7, the algorithm suggests removing the element with array index 4, thus the new state *data_state_temp* would thus be [2,1,3]. Currently it checks whether it has seen the state so far via

```
flag_cycle = (data_state_temp in data_state_list)
```

The algorithm checks the new state for adding/removing different array elements until `flag_cycle` is `False`, then proceeds.

Apart from that it does not yet fully work, because the states [2,1,3] from iteration 7 and [2,3,1] from iteration 3 are the same, but the lists are not (need to sort them or better insert newly removed array elements into where they would belong in a sorted list), the problem is that the algorithm becomes very slow. In practice, e.g. `data_state_temp` has length 15000, and `data_state_list` has 40000 lists with generally increasing length up to 15000.

**Questions:**

- How can we get a speed-up for that cycle/infinite loop check? Other/Conceptually different approaches to checking whether we already had the same state previously are perfectly fine.
- In the current code, when Python checks whether `data_state_temp` is in `data_state_list`, does it compare list elements only for lists with lengths matching that of `data_state_temp` (I would expect that) or would we need to manually select these lists beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Keep History as Set (Fixed Lookup)

If you do not care about the order of past states -- just that it was ever visited before -- then lets amass a `set` of all past states.  This gives us a fixed lookup instead of linear lookup with `in` (e.g. `for needle in haystack`)

For a `set` to work its magic, it has to work with hashable types.  In short, a `tuple` is immutable and therefore hashable and therefore a shoe-in candidate to be used with `set`.

```
from itertools import chain

# let's say we already have state that is 15000 long
data_states = set()
data_state = tuple(range(15000))
data_states.add(data_state)

# we loop until we decide on a new state
while data_state in data_states:
    # either you decide to remove an element, say 42
    # (can skip sort because the previous tuple was already sorted)
    new_data_state = tuple(x for x in data_state if x != 42)

    # or you decide to add an element, 9000
    new_data_state = tuple(sorted(x for x in chain(data_state, [9000])))

    data_state = new_data_state

# now commit this state to your history
data_states.add(new_data_state)
```

Note that tuple is immutable, so we have to sort first before creating the tuple.  Also note the `sorted(_)` form creates a copy, whereas `_.sort()` performs in-place sort.  Since we are parsing previous state as a generator, the latter sort would not be possible as we do not have memory.  So former is picked.  Then that is fed into `tuple()` constructor.

### Runtime Complexity

Given `len(state) = n`:

```
new_data_state = tuple(sorted(x for x in chain(data_state, [9000])))
```

1. `x for x in ...`: generator with `n` operations
2. `sorted(...)`: creates a list, populates with `n` entries
3. `tuple(...)`: creates a tuple, populates `n` entries

Steps 1+2 happen in one pass of `n`.  Then repeat `n` for Step 3.  Total runtime complexity is `O{2n}` per iteration of `state`.

### Q: How to speed up?

What I listed above.  If you become strapped for memoery, you might consider more compact forms of representing `state`.

For example, you might chunk `state` into `3` chunks consisting of `5000` consecutive numbers.  Then use a nested dictionary.  E.g. `data_states[(x for x in range(5000)][(x for x in range(5000)] == <all the remaining digits>`

In this way, the space cost is amortized such that the incremental space cost for an element with `15777` digits is only `15777 - 5000 - 5000 = 5777` digits.  This is essentially what a dictionary does.

### Q: Does it compare list elements by length?

Yes, it performs length matching as the first check to short-circuit a `False`.  But no, it still processes every single element.

Comment: Using a set indeed seems a good idea. So far I used lists instead of tuples inside the outer structure, where I would create the new_data_state as `new_data_state = data_states[-1].copy()` and then `new_data_state = bisect.insort(new_data_state, elem)` for removing a data point and `new_data_state.remove(elem)` for adding a data point to the sample; Is that slower than the `sorted(generator_expression)` construction you presented?

Comment: The benefit of `bisect.insort` is you are working with sorted data and thus can use binary search to find an element in `O{log(n)}`.  But remember, you just performed a full copy which is `O{n}`.  With my approach, the copy and filter happen in the same pass in `O{n}`.  At the end of the day, you will have benchmark both to know which is faster because they have the same order of runtime complexity.

Comment: I would say at best your approach is as fast as mine, and potentially slower.  The reason is `bisect.insort` is essentially performing exactly what my code is doing (make a full copy with filter).  However, your approach additionally performs a full copy before `bisect.insort` which mine does not.

Comment: And just converting the tuple to a list, then using `bisect.insort` and converting back to a tuple would also create a full copy, correct?

Comment: @bproxauf that would incur `O{3n + log(n)}`: `n` from tuple to list, `n` from bisect needs to copy your list after cutting it, and `log(n)` it has to search, `n` for back to tuple.

Comment: @bproxauf added runtime complexity analysis to answer TL;DR it is `O{2n}` vs `O{3n + log(n)}`  .  Also, I removed `sorted()` from the case of removing an element since the previous state tuple would already be sorted.

Comment: Hmm, in my algorithm the tuple-list-tuple conversion was in practice faster than the `sorted(generator_expression)`, but I guess asymptotically does not always apply (coefficients in front of complexity)... Anyways, the most important change is the outer usage of `set` instead of a `list`, and the time per iteration remains now pretty much constant instead of growing after some point.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for providing a lot of info as well, it is much appreciated!